# Why was Fatboy Slim credited for "Praise You"?

Tags: fatboy-slim

From what I can tell, "Praise You" consists almost entirely of a modified  from "Take Yo' Praise" by Camille Yarbrough, with a few other samples thrown in.

It seems to me it should be labeled as a remix of that song, and Fatboy Slim would be credited as -- I don't know, "Producer" or something. Yet Wikipedia calls it "a song by Fatboy Slim". Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a long "tradition" of musicians --especially white British musicians --treating black American music like a freely available natural resource, something that doesn't need to be credited, and that becomes "your" creation with only the most minor modifications (see ["Freight Train"](http://biography.yourdictionary.com/elizabeth-cotten), ["Come Together"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Come_Together) and ["The Lemon Song"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lemon_Song) for famous examples).  In this case, however, it seems Ms. Yarbrough was credited as co-writer and presumably given her fair share of royalties.  Given the popularity of Fatboy Slim's version, perhaps that was enough for her.  In addition, she experienced a bit of a career renaissance in the wake of the song, likely from those who did take the time to trace down the original track.

In all fairness to Fatboy Slim, the Yarbrough sample, although prominent, is only a small part of the original song, and his usage of it creates a song quite different in feel, structure and impact to the original.  Creating a new song through sampling does continue to be a moral, legal and creative gray area for many people, but it is generally accepted that sampling legitimately creates a new song, as long as the original artists are credited and compensated appropriately.

A lot of where the line gets drawn in practice depends on the litigiousness of the allegedly infringed party.  There is a particularly aggressive and successful legal team protecting every possible usage of Rolling Stones music, which famously won 100% of the royalties from the song "Bitter Sweet Symphony," a song most people would have characterized as an original composition. In that case, as in many others where copyright infringement is aggressively pursued, it is often at the initiation, and to the enrichment, of a publishing company or a management team, rather than the artists themselves (who may or may not even share in the awarded damages themselves).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_issues_surrounding_music_sampling for more.

Comment: The Stones have got ZILCH to do WRT the lawsuit over "Bitter Sweet Symphony", this is widely documented. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitter_Sweet_Symphony#Song_credits

Comment: @BCdotWEB It's always the management company!  :)  I tried to express that, but I have edited to make it more clear.